# Ruby - How to associate method with another method

Tags: ruby, expression

I'm new to Ruby, and expect to use methods inside of method or associate construct_const method with interpret method. Interpret method should simply return the value for this constant

```
def construct_const(value) 
  def interpret()
      return @value
   end
end
```

```
 e = construct_const(0)
    assert_equal(0, e.interpret)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your posting, you are using `value` and `@value`. I guess this is a typo, since you are not refering `value` anywhere in your example code, so I assume that you wanted to use `value` in your `interpret` method, not `@value`.

You can define a method on the fly for a certain object using [`define_singleton_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method), i.e.

```
def construct_const(value)
  define_singleton_method(:interpret) { value }
end
```

With this, if you do then a

```
e.construct_const
```

the variable `e` will then have a new method 'interpret` attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you define `interpret` method inside `construct_const` you get a `:interpret` symbol as the result of calling `construct_const`. Because every statement returns a value defining a method returns the method name.

```
> def interpret()
>   return @value
> end
=> :interpret
```

So each time you call `construct_const` you define a method and return its name.

Also, you mismatch a local variable `value` and an instance variable `@value`.

You can use [lambda or proc](https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/) to return a function, the function will have `call` method:

```
def construct_const(value) 
  -> { value }
end

> e = construct_const(0)
=> #<Proc:0x000055c060a47f60@(irb):12 (lambda)> 
> e.call
=> 0
```

You can define an anonymous [class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Class.html) with a method `interpret`:

```
def construct_const(value)
   my_class = Class.new do
     def initialize(value)
       @value = value
     end

     def interpret
       @value # Here you can use an instance variable because it's inside of the anonymous class
     end
   end
   my_class.new(value) # Pass a value to initialize a new instance
end

> e = construct_const(0)
=> #<#<Class:0x0000563663366c68>:0x0000563663366b50 @value=0> 
> e.interpret
=> 0
```

A similar solution but with a predefined class:

```
class Interpreter
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def interpret
    @value
  end
end

def construct_const(value)
   Interpreter.new(value)
end

> e = construct_const(0)
=> #<Interpreter:0x0000563663367b68 @value=0> 
> e.interpret
=> 0
```

A solutions with [`Struct`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Struct.html) object:

```
def construct_const(value)
   Struct.new(:interpret).new(value)
end

> e = construct_const(0)
=> #<struct interpret=0> 
> e.interpret
=> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably had better answers already, but as far as I can see, these seem to work (though I don't really know what I'm doing):

```
def construct_const(value)
    mod = Module.new
    mod.module_eval do
        define_method :interpret do
            value
        end
    end
    obj = Object.new
    obj.extend(mod)
    obj
end

e = construct_const(0)
=> #<Object:0x00000000084a0e90>
e.interpret
=> 0
```

```
def construct_const(value)
    obj = Object.new
    obj.instance_eval do
        @value = value
        def interpret
            @value
        end
    end
    obj
end

e = construct_const(0)
=> #<Object:0x000000000a369098 @value=0>
e.interpret
=> 0
```